# Pass a parameter to a WCF service constructor

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, self-hosting

I need to pass an **exist** DI container as a parameter to a WCF service constructor
In order to do that i'm using IInstanceProvider
The WCF service should be hosted in self host.

```
public class CustomInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider, IContractBehavior
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer UnityContainer;

    public CustomInstanceProvider(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        if (unityContainer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("unityContainer");
        }

        UnityContainer = unityContainer;
    }


    #region Implementation of IInstanceProvider

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return new Service(UnityContainer);
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        return this.GetInstance(instanceContext);
    }
    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {

    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IContractBehavior

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = this;

    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {

    }


    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    #endregion
}
```

I also implement CustomServiceHost

```
  public class CustomServiceHost : ServiceHost
    {
        public CustomServiceHost(IUnityContainer unityContainer, Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
        : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
    {
        if (unityContainer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("unityContainer is null");
        }

        foreach (var cd in this.ImplementedContracts.Values)
        {
            cd.Behaviors.Add(new CustomInstanceProvider(unityContainer));
        }

    }
}
```

and ServiceHostFactory

```
public class CustomServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer UnityContainer;
    public CustomServiceHostFactory(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        UnityContainer = unityContainer;
    }

    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType,
        Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return new CustomServiceHost(UnityContainer, serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }
```

}

I creates WCF Service :

```
           var uris = new Uri[1];
        uris[0] = new Uri("http://localhost:8793/Service/");
        CustomServiceHostFactory factory = new CustomServiceHostFactory(Container);
        CustomServiceHost serviceHost =  (CustomServiceHost)factory.CreateServiceHost("guy",uris);
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WSHttpBinding(), "");
        serviceHost.Open();
```

I am getting an exception :

```
 An exception occurred while initializing module 'PluginsModule'. 

- The exception message was: 'ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost' cannot be invoked within the current hosting environment. This API requires that the calling application be hosted in IIS or WAS.

- The Assembly that the module was trying to be loaded from was:<"PluginsModule.plugin" , Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Check the InnerException property of the exception for more information. If the exception occurred while creating an object in a DI container, you can exception.GetRootException() to help locate the root cause of the problem.
```

Please help

thanks.

Comment: Don't you want to call CreateServiceHost with a type as the first param not a string? That is the method you have overriden

Comment: does `return new CustomServiceHost(UnityContainer, serviceType, baseAddresses);` get called when you call `(CustomServiceHost)factory.CreateServiceHost("guy",uris);`?

Comment: no, I also override CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
and it gets there and fails when i am calling to return base.CreateServiceHost(constructorString, baseAddresses)
inside it

Comment: `public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost
    (string service, Uri[] baseAddresses)

  {

   // The service parameter is ignored here because we know our service.
   ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloService),
    baseAddresses);
   return serviceHost;

  }`

Comment: The previous comment was from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344725.aspx

Comment: not sure you want to call the base

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, 
The problem was that I don't need to use the CustomInstanceProvider.
ServiecInstanceProvider is only for IIS use.
I want my service to be hosted in self-host.

```
        var uris = new Uri[1];
        uris[0] = new Uri("http://localhost:8793//Service/ntService/");
        var serviceHost = new CustomServiceHost(Container,typeof(Service),uris);
        serviceHost.AddDefaultEndpoints();
```

Thats all I needed to to:
Implement IInstanceProvider & ServiceHost.
Now I can pass parameter to my constructor.

Thanks